# Image change with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, src

I'm newbie at javascript. I want to know what I'm doing wrong. I want to make image src swap on function onclick. After first click my image change to "close" but everytime more it seems to be closed. Just in case, I don't want other solution. I just want to know what is going wrong on my script. Thanks!

```js
function menuOpenClose()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-icon")

    if (a.src === "icon/menu.svg") {
        a.src = "icon/close.svg";
    } else {
        a.src = "icon/menu.svg";
    }
}
```

```css
img {
        display: block;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="menuOpenClose();">
  <img id="mobile-menu-icon" src="icon/menu.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: In your if statement you are not comparing but assigning. Use a double or triple equal sign to compare the variable with the string.

Comment: I've removed the syntax mistake that's acting as a red herring here. New answers should address the issue with `a.src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways ([indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)):

```
if (a.src.indexOf("icon/menu.svg") != -1) {
```

or:

```
if (a.getAttribute('src') == "icon/menu.svg") {
```

The snippet:

```js
function menuOpenClose()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-icon")

    //if (a.getAttribute('src').indexOf("icon/menu.svg") != -1) {
    if (a.getAttribute('src') == "icon/menu.svg") {
        a.src = "icon/close.svg";
    } else {
        a.src = "icon/menu.svg";
    }
    console.log(a.src);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="menuOpenClose();">
    <img id="mobile-menu-icon" src="icon/menu.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the if statement should be like below

```
   if (a.src === "icon/menu.svg") {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an assignment operator in your `if statement` instead of a comparison operator.

Change this:

```
if (a.src = "icon/menu.svg")
```

To this:

```
if (a.src === "icon/menu.svg")
```

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above approach:

```css
/* CSS */
img {display: block;width: 32px;height: 32px;}
```

```html
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
function menuOpenClose(){
    var a = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-icon")

    if (a.src === "https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=0") {
        a.src = "https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1";
    } else {
        a.src = "https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=0";
    }
}
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="menuOpenClose();">
  <img id="mobile-menu-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=0">
</div>
```

Comment: If I change it my image didn't change even in first click.

Comment: @ownidea Check the demo **Code Snippet** I added in the answer using your exact code but with the proper operator `===` used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change = to === it a different:

`a.src === "icon/menu.svg"` this correct

Second as you can see you never will change you image because your condition can't catch it.

this is anwer from console:

```
@>src https://stacksnippets.net/icon/menu.svg
```

you always do `else`

```js
        function menuOpenClose() {
            var a = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-icon")

            console.log(`@>src`,a.src)

            if (a.src === "icon/menu.svg") {
                a.src = "icon/close.svg";
            } else {
                a.src = "icon/menu.svg";
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="menuOpenClose();">
    <img id="mobile-menu-icon" src="icon/menu.svg">
</div>
```